# How to every 12th elements in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that contains monthly data over several years.

The 1st column contains dates (and is named `date`).

The 2nd column contains monthly data (and is name `data`).

This is a dataframe, and I don't wish to resort on a specific R package.

How do I compute the average for each month (Jan to Dec)?
That is how do I compute the average of every 12th element in my `data` column?

Here is example data

```
date    data
01-83   498957
02-83   493861
03-83   496304
04-83   422322
05-83   379474
06-83   319446
07-83   332270
08-83   362075
09-83   318477
10-83   283378
11-83   214823
12-83   185131
01-84   160663
02-84   192201
03-84   212521
04-84   249950
05-84   274998
06-84   332064
07-84   364159
08-84   384619
09-84   439380
10-84   445955
11-84   493763
12-84   463612
01-85   314638
02-85   368237
03-85   254565
04-85   201342
05-85   230851
06-85   227190
07-85   264440
08-85   297501
09-85   503771
10-85   698504
11-85   768215
12-85   852077
01-86   939023
02-86   941674
03-86   861596
04-86   810595
05-86   666097
06-86   643074
07-86   640936
08-86   626805
09-86   615487
10-86   650764
11-86   665444
12-86   565598
01-87   511561
02-87   475577
03-87   451673
04-87   406587
05-87   394605
06-87   429394
07-87   509071
08-87   567143
09-87   664491
10-87   688447
11-87   602141
12-87   513640
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data...

Comment: hi. i first didn't posted data as long columns are a bit boring in this forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
> tapply(df$data,substr(df$date,1,2),mean)
      01       02       03       04       05       06       07       08       09       10       11       12 
484968.4 494310.0 455331.8 418159.2 389205.0 390233.6 422175.2 447628.6 508321.2 553409.6 548877.2 516011.6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mean(df[df$date=="January","data"])
#etc. for each month...
```

EDIT (based on seeing the actual data):

```
by(df$data,substr(df$date,1,2),FUN=mean)
```